# place file on https location using powershell

Tags: powershell, https

I am trying to place a file on https location uisng powershell. I am using below code to place the file

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $imanagepath -Method Post -InFile $filepath -UseDefaultCredentials
```

But i am getting below error:

```
The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.
```

Please suggest.

Comment: The server is not allowing a POST method.  Does server allow uploads?